# Remove ECB from XsltListViewWebPart

Tags: web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part, splist

I have created XsltListViewWebPart programatically.
I want to remove ecb on list items, I know this can be done by changing xsl of the webpart but I am getting null in it.
Is there any way to do this?